# call FragmentActivity in another class?

Tags: android, android-studio, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

when I want call a fragment I use this code:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
...
new PrimaryFragment()
...
```

and I create fargment this form:

```
public class PrimaryFragmentextends Fragment {...}
```

Now I have class this form:

```
public class PrimaryFragment extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {...}
```

how can I call it in another activity class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go from one **Activity** to another **Activity** (Like from Activity A to Activity B)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

If you want to go from **Fragment** to **Activity** (Like from Fragment A to Activity B)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), B.class);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your class extends FragmentActivity, you start it the same way as any other Activity, namely:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PrimaryFragment.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html